# Processes in Python 3.9 exiting with code 1 when It's created inside a ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-3.8, python-3.9

I've a piece of code that submits a task to a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) which starts a [Process](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process). I've realised that in Python 3.8 that Process finished with exit code `0`. But I've updated Python to the 3.9 version and this started to finishing with exit code `1`! Even when the Process executes an empty task.

Here's a minimal example:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def some_task():
    pass


def execute_error():
    p = Process(target=some_task)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print(p.exitcode)  # This is always 1 on a ThreadPoolExecutor!!!


executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
executor.submit(execute_error)
# execute_error()  # IMPORTANT: this works correctly (exit 0)
```

My versions:

```
Ubuntu 21.04
Python 3.9.4
```

**Note** that if `__execute_error` is called outside the ThreadPoolExecutor it works correctly. Is there I am missing? Is this a Python 3.9 bug? Is there any workaround? Any kind of help would be really appreciated

Comment: Interesting find. I can confirm the 3.8/3.9 discrepancy. Also, seems like `ProcessPoolExecutor` always returns 0 as expected, only `ThreadPoolExecutor` is affected.

Comment: I've submitted an issue with the same title to the Python issue tracker

Comment: That's awkward! Could you leave a link to the issue you posted for posterity?

Comment: Yes sorry! I commented from the cellphone where I didn't have the link. Here it is: https://bugs.python.org/issue43944

Answer (score 1):

The `multiprocessing` module provides 3 methods of starting a process: `spawn`, `fork`, and `forkserver`. My guess is that you are using a Unix-based system which defaults to the `fork` method. The documentation for `fork` mentions:

> Note that safely **forking a multithreaded process is problematic**.

- `fork` copies the entire process at the call site which runs into above issue.
- `spawn` creates a fresh Python process from scratch and passes needed resources to it.
- `forkserver` creates a single-threaded server process which will be used as a template to fork future processes from. As it is single-threaded this fork is safe.

Based on my testing, and the descriptions, **choosing either `spawn` or `forkserver` should work for you and lead to `exitcode` 0**.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, set_start_method
set_start_method('spawn')
```

The regression from Python 3.8 to 3.9 for the `fork` method is worrying to me however, so I left [a comment](https://bugs.python.org/issue39812) on the Python bug tracker. Maybe someone will fix this issue but as I said, as far as the documentation is concerned, forking a multithreaded process is just not supported.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for your answer. I've submitted an issue too: https://bugs.python.org/issue43944. I'll wait to get an answer from the official community before I close this question